# How to compare a time value in Excel when the range goes past midnight

Tags: excel, time, range, comparison

I need to compare the time in a given cell (say A1) against a range of times to see if it falls within the range.  Here is the data:

```
Site 1      11:30 PM     2:30 AM

Site 2      10:00 PM     3:00 AM

Site 3       2:00 PM     8:00 PM
```

So if a value of 12:00 AM (midnight) is entered in A1, Site 1 and Site 2 should be True, Site 3 False
If a value of 3:00 PM is entered in A1, Site 1 and Site 2 should be False, Site 3 True.

Can't seem to get Excel to do this.  Note:  I cannot change the format of the cells to include a date.

Comment: It seems you already know that adding 1 to the next day times would solve your problem,  but can't update the raw data with that.   But you can do it in the formula that returns TRUE/FALSE.  So, wherever you refer to the second time, eg `C2` use `C2+If(C2<B2,1,0)` instead

Comment: There are also possible ambiguous data sets.  eg Site X 4:00 AM to 2:00 AM and you are testing 1:00 AM.  Is that 1:00 AM on the first day (answer FALSE) or the second day (answer TRUE)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are techniques you can use to determine the decimal value of time.

Firstly, a general understanding:

- `12:00:00 AM` is the beginning of the day (same as `00:00:00`) so its value is 0.
- `12:00:00 PM` is noon and its value is 0.5 (1 half of a whole day).

---

To see the value of time, you can do any of the following:

- `=VALUE(A1)`
- `=TEXT(A1,"0.0000000000")` (zeros are based on how specific you want the decimal to be)
- `format the cell (ctrl-1 / right click > "Format Cells") > Number tab > Set Category to General`

---

Applying the above to your situation, the following formula will check for AM/PM status, subtract 1 (1 day) if the time is PM. This gives a 24 hour comparison between times. Using the `AND()` function, we can now compare between 2 values and return `TRUE` or `FALSE` accordingly.

Assuming the format is the same as the attached images, add this to `C2` and drag down as needed:

`=IF(AND(IF($A$1>0.5,$A$1-1,$A$1)>=IF(A2>0.5,A2-1,A2),IF($A$1>0.5,$A$1-1,$A$1)<=IF(B2>0.5,B2-1,B2)),TRUE,FALSE)`

[image]

[image]